# Background subtraction

Tags: image-processing, opencv, background-subtraction

I'm doing background subtraction using opencv. The problem is the foreground object is not always detected correctly. To deal with this I would like to use four or five images, and take their average as the background image. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to describe what you are doing in more detail to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps go through all the images, and if the pixel in question is within a certain range of colour variation for all the images, disregard it as background?

Then I suppose the size of the range would determine how picky you were and how confident you are in the stability and consistency of your camera.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the included background detector in OpenCV (under cvaux.h). They also have blob detector if you want to find object blob.

By combining blob information and optical flow information, you can usually find the foreground object.